# How does copyout() in xv6 avoid race condition in the page table?

Tags: operating-system, xv6

```c
// Copy from kernel to user.
// Copy len bytes from src to virtual address dstva in a given page table.
// Return 0 on success, -1 on error.
int
copyout(pagetable_t pagetable, uint64 dstva, char *src, uint64 len)
{
  uint64 n, va0, pa0;

  while(len > 0){
    va0 = PGROUNDDOWN(dstva);
    pa0 = walkaddr(pagetable, va0);
    if(pa0 == 0)
      return -1;
    n = PGSIZE - (dstva - va0);
    if(n > len)
      n = len;
    memmove((void *)(pa0 + (dstva - va0)), src, n);

    len -= n;
    src += n;
    dstva = va0 + PGSIZE;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The function used in xv6 kernel for copying out data from the kernel to user-space process accepts a pagetable as argument and uses that pagetable to access the physical address behind that user-space address. However, neither `copyout()` nor `walkaddr()` performs any locking operation on the page table. How are race conditions avoided in this case? Is it possible for the page table to change after getting the physical address and before the actual reading and cause issues? And how is it avoided in xv6?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, the copyout() is invoked by the kernel in the

piperead() and pipewrite() located in pipewrite.c function. Prior to calling this

function the calling process's spinlock is already held.